# Event layer to feature class - fastest method?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, feature-class

There are three methods to [convert the output of a Make XY Event Layer to a Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000006z000000):

- Copy Features
- Feature to Point
- Feature Class to Feature Class

Which one is the fastest method? I need to convert a huge amount of points stored in a csv table (1,5 GB  file) and I wonder what's the best way to do it.

I will use Background geoprocessing on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Background geoprocessing is slower.

Comment: Really? Recently I've run into problems with foreground processing (out of memory). I understood Background processing (64-bit) is the right solution when processing huge amount of data.

Comment: Hi Manuel. If you have a CSV table with LatLon coordinates and want to create a new feature class out of it - and know a little Python - the quickest way would be to use the `csv` module to read each line, then use an [insert cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) to [write the geometries](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/python/writing-geometries.htm) to a blank feature class. I've used this technique and it's much faster than any ArcGIS out-of-the-box geoprocessing tool, especially for huge CSV files.

Comment: I explain the same in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32207/discussion-between-geostonemarten-and-manuel-frias) . Your csv is reconize as table by arcgis. You can use a couple of da.searchCursor and da.insertCursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of technique I mentioned in the my comment to your question. Reading a CSV and populating a feature class with its values can be easy. The script assumes the *Latitude* field is the 1st column and *Longitude* field is the 2nd column. You can tweak the coordinate system in the code to something other than WGS84, tweak the field types, etc.

```python
# Author: John K. Tran
# Contact: jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu

import arcpy
import os
import csv
print "arcpy imported"

"""
Input CSV can look like:

Lat,Lon,First Name,Last Name
12.34,56.78,Joe,Smith
0.98,7.65,Jane,Doe
65.43,43.21,Bob,Sagat

Make sure 'Lat' and 'Lon' fields are the 1st and 2nd column in the CSV respectively.

"""

incsv = r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\My Docs\Sample Data\SampleCSV.csv" # Change this to the path of your CSV file.
outfc = r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\My Docs\Sample Data\SampleGDB.gdb\SampleFC" # Change this to the path of your output FC.

spatialref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # Create the spatial reference object as WGS84. Can modify if desired.

if not arcpy.Exists(outfc): # Create the output feature class if needed.
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outfc), os.path.basename(outfc), "POINT", None, None, None, spatialref)

csv.register_dialect("xls", delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n") # Register the dialect for native CSV syntax in Microsoft Excel.
f = open(incsv, "r") 
reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = "xls")

headers = reader.next() # Read the first line as the header names.

for header in headers[2:]: # Add fields for remaining columns if needed. Default is TEXT field.
    arcpy.AddField_management(outfc, header, "TEXT")

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, ['SHAPE@XY'] + headers[2:]) # Create InsertCursor.
count = 0
for row in reader:
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print "processing row {0}".format(count)
    Ycoord = row[0] # Make sure 'Lat' is in the 1st column.
    Xcoord = row[1] # Make sure 'Lon' is in the 2nd column.
    newrow = [(float(Xcoord), float(Ycoord))] + row[2:]
    cursor.insertRow(newrow) # Insert point in FC for each row in CSV.
    count += 1

del cursor
f.close()
```

And example of a CSV that can be read is:

```
Lat,Lon,FirstName,LastName,Tone,Magnitude
26.61,-81.49,John,Smith,Dark,6.0
26.68,-81.47,Jim,Jones,Light,9.0
20.01,-155.87,Steve,Bruin,Medium,3.9
25.43,-80.45,Bob,Johnson,Dark,2.75
26.05,-80.11,Bill,Mayer,Light,26.6
```

100,000 CSV records took about 3-5 seconds for me to run.

Comment: Absolutely amazing. 18 minutes to process 1,7 GB csv file. It took *hours* with the ArcGIS tools. Thanks for sharing this gem!

Comment: @John yeah today i can see original script and it create all fields in text... Perfect and sure it work. Look at based [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171653/error-adding-row-sequence-size-must-match-size-of-row)

Answer (score 4):

I've found a model builder model to be fastest with: "Make X Y Event Layer" followed by "Feature class to Feature Class"

[image: model example]

Comment: BTW: I've seen more than a few issues with "make x y event layer" over the years, if you have issues export the csv to a geodatabase table (as an intermediate) then use that as the input.

Comment: if you have time could you visit this question?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283659/proper-parameters-for-featureclasstofeatureclass-arcpy-tool