# arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion() gives ERROR 000732: Output Location: Dataset ... does not exist or is not supported?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, error-000732

I'm trying to write a script to convert CSV to Feature Class (overwriting if pre-existing).

Unfortunately my version of Arc (10.2.2) does not have "XYTableToPoint()" so I needed to find another way.

I employed [the suggestion made by "GISI"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK8lZ.png) in response to this question: "[Event layer to feature class - fastest method?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160002/event-layer-to-feature-class-fastest-method)", but here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\scripts\CSVtoASMADPointFeatureClass.py", line 23, in <module>
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Temp_Layer, Target_GDB, Target_FC_name, "", "" , "")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1675, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Output Location: Dataset Q:\Data\Stations.gdb\Stations does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
```

Apparently the problem is with my parameters.

When I read [ESRI's documentation on FeatureClasstoFeatureClass](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) I saw their first example using only the first 3 paramaters, so I figured I was fine to just use the first 3 as well (last 3 optional).

For example, I didn't think I should need the 5th parameter (Field Mappings) because I want all the fields exactly as they are in the original CSV.

**What is wrong with the Parameters as used in the "FeatureClassToFeatureClass" Arcpy Tool below?**

```
import arcpy
Source_CSV = r"\\int.ec\Data\Stations.csv"
Target_FC = r"Q:\Data\Stations.gdb\Stations"
Description = arcpy.Describe(Target_FC)
Target_FC_name = Description.name
Target_GDB = Description.catalogPath
Temp_Layer = "Temp_Layer"
SR = arcpy.Describe(Target_FC).spatialReference
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Source_CSV, "Lng", "Lat", Temp_Layer, SR, "")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Temp_Layer, Target_GDB, Target_FC_name, "", "", "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this **code snippet** produces the same error as your full code then it suggests that on the `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion()` line you are specifying a full pathname to a feature class instead of a location (geodatabase or folder) for your `out_path`

```
import arcpy
Source_CSV = r"\\int.ec\Data\Stations.csv"
Target_FC = r"Q:\Data\Stations.gdb\Stations"
Description = arcpy.Describe(Target_FC)
Target_FC_name = Description.name
Target_GDB = Description.catalogPath
Temp_Layer = "Temp_Layer"
SR = arcpy.Describe(Target_FC).spatialReference
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Source_CSV, "Lng", "Lat", Temp_Layer, SR, "")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Temp_Layer, Target_GDB, Target_FC_name, "", "" , "")
```

You seem to be assuming that `arcpy.Describe().catalogPath` returns a location.  You should `print(Target_GDB)` to be certain about what it returns.

Comment: Touché.  Fixed with Target_GDB = os.path.split(Description.catalogPath) [0].  Thanks.